# Proofe: $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$: $\ker(f^n) = \ker(f^{n_0}) \forall n \geq n_0$ and $\ker(f^n) \subsetneq \ker(f^{n+1}) \forall n < n_0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a Vector space and $f: V \to V$ a linear map. Let $\dim (V)$ be finite.

I have to show that $\exists n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $\ker (f^n)$ = $\ker (f^{n_0})$ for all $n \ge n_0$ and that $\ker(f^{n}) \subset \ker(f^{n+1})$ for all $n < n_0$.

I showed, that $\ker(f) \subseteq \ker(f^2) \subseteq \ldots \subseteq \ker(f^n) \subseteq \ldots$

Since $\dim(V) < \infty$
\begin{align}
\dim(V) = & \operatorname{rank}(f) + \dim(\ker(f)) \\
\dim(V) = & \dim(\operatorname{im}(f)) + \dim(\ker(f)) \\
\dim(\operatorname{im}(f)) = & \dim(V) - \dim(\ker(f))
\end{align}

So if I show that there exists and $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$, such that
\begin{align}
\operatorname{im}(f^n) & = \operatorname{im}(f^{n_0}) \quad \forall n \geq n_0 \\
\operatorname{im}(f^{n+1}) & \subsetneq \operatorname{im}(f^{n}) \quad \forall n \geq n_0
\end{align}
the above statement follows. But i struggle to show this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: The sequence $\text{dim}(\ker(f^n))$ is an increasing sequence of numbers that is bounded above by $\text{dim}(V)$, so it has to terminate at some stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the sequence $\{\ker(f^n)\}$ can not increase dimension forever, there is at least one $n_0$ such that $\ker(f^{n_0})=\ker(f^{n_0+1})$.

Assume that $\ker(f^n)=\ker(f^{n+1})$.

Let $v\in \ker(f^{n+2})$, then $f^{n+2}v=f^{n+1} fv=0$.

So $fv\in \ker(f^{n+1})=\ker(f^n)$.

Then $f^n fv = f^{n+1}v=0$, thus $v\in\ker(f^{n+1})$.

The other inclusion is trivial. We have proved that $\ker(f^{n+1})=\ker(f^{n+2})$.

If we pick $n_0$ to be the least element in the set
$$
\{n| \dim\ker(f^n)=\dim\ker(f^{n+1})\}$$

Then we have $\ker(f^n)=\ker(f^{n+1})$ for all $n\geq n_0$, and

$\ker(f^n)\subsetneq \ker(f^{n+1})$ for all $n<n_0$.