# Show that there exists a non-negative integer $r$ s.t. $\ker(T^r) = \ker(T^{r+1})$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Question: Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional complex vector space, let $T: V \to V$ be a linear transformation. Show that there exists a non-negative integer $r$ s.t. $\ker(T^r) = \ker(T^{r+1})$.

My attempt: Let $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $v \in V$ be s.t. $v \in \ker(T^i)$. Then $T^i(v) = 0$, whence $T(T^i(v)) = T(0) = 0$. So $v \in \ker(T^{i+1})$.

So I have shown $\forall i \in \mathbb{N}: \ker(T^i) \subseteq \ker(T^{i+1})$. I suspect we need $\exists r \in \mathbb{N}, \forall v \in V: T^r(v) = 0$, from which the proof would proceed trivially. But cannot quite see how to get it...

Comment: Remember that $V$ is finite-dimensional. You have an ascending chain $\text{ker}(T)\subseteq \text{ker}(T^2)\subseteq \cdots\subseteq \text{ker}(T^i)\subseteq\cdots\subseteq V$ of subspaces. They each have finite dimension.

Comment: The assertion in the last paragraph is probably not true: suppose $T$ is invertible, for example. This has probably been asked before on this site but anyway: you really need to use finite-dimensionality (example?) together with this relation $\ker T^i \subseteq \ker T^{i+1}$. I think those are really the only ingredients.

Comment: Your suspect is not right. $T^rv=0$ for all $v$ means that $T^r$ is zero matrix. Example: $T=I$, is it possible to get some power zero?

Comment: @HowDoIMath: So from $ker(T^i) \subseteq ker(T^{i+1})$ I get $dim(ker(T^i)) < dim(ker(T^{i+1})$. So I have $r \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. $dim(ker(T^r)) = dim(V)$? and then because $ker(T^r) \subseteq V$, I have $ker(T^r) = V$?

Comment: Duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602584/proofe-exists-n-0-in-mathbbn-kerfn-kerfn-0-forall-n-geq

Comment: Actually, rubbish I don't even need that last part. Right, got it now, cheers! (also sorry for the duplicate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and $U\neq V$, then $\dim U<\dim V$.