# Show that there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $\ker (S^n)=\ker (S^{n+1})$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Any help with the following question...

> Let $S: \textsf{V} \to \textsf{V}$ be a linear operator. Show that if $\textsf{V}$ is finite-dimensional, there exists $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ such that $\ker (S^n)=\ker (S^{n+1})$. In this case, $\ker (S^k) \nsubseteq \ker (S^{k+1})$ for all $k<n$.
>
> Proof a similar result for $\text{im} (S^n)$.

Comment: Please show your attempt

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/602584/proofe-exists-n-0-in-mathbbn-kerfn-kerfn-0-forall-n-geq?rq=1

Comment: The use of "problem statement questions" is discouraged, by which I mean posts that ask for "[a]ny help" with an exercise "quoted" but not otherwise described.  It would seem to many Readers that all the ingredients needed to show the result are provided in the quoted exercise, and it thus becomes a guessing game about what needs to be addressed.  E.g. do you understand what $V$ is finite dimensional means?  Is it clear that $\operatorname{ker}(S^k) \subseteq \operatorname{ker}(S^{k+1})$ for all $k\in \mathbb Z^+$?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$v\in\ker S\implies S^2v=S(Sv)=S(0)=0\implies \ker S\subset \ker S^2$$

So begin constructing an ascending series $\;\ker S\subset\ker S^2\subset\ker S^3\subset\ldots\;$, and then use finite dimensionality.